# Is $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x\in\mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & \text{ if } x\notin \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$ Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x\in\mathbb{Q} \\  0 & \text{ if } x\notin \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$ Lebesgue measurable ?

---

I haven't study rigorous the chapter of measurable function, so I don't have many tools to work on this.

My idea was to say that since $f^{-1}(0)=\{\mathbb{Q}\}$ Which is measurable and
$f^{-1}(1)=\{\mathbb{R\setminus Q}\}$ which is also measurable then $f$ is measurable, I don't think it's correct.  How should I prove this (if $f$ is even measurable)?

Comment: $f^{-1}(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{R}$, because every real number maps to a rational. You meant $f^{-1}(\{0\}) =\mathbb{Q}$ and $f^{-1}(\{1\}) = \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ is a Borel set, so its indicator is measurable

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: A function is Lebesgue measurable if the inverse image of every set of the form $(a,\infty)$, for $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is measurable. Here, the inverse image is either empty (measurable), $\mathbb{Q}$ (countable, hence measurable), or $\mathbb{R}$, which is measurable, so this function is lebesgue measurable.

Comment: @Displayname: No, the inverse image of anything is either empty, $\mathbb{Q}$, its completement, or all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Displayname This does not make sense at all. How can "inverse of anything" could be a subset of $\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$, since the function is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe yes you are correct I wrote the wrong thing, i will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea, using $f^{-1}$ is correct, but $f^{-1}(\mathbb{Q})=\{0\}, f^{-1}(\mathbb{R\setminus Q})=\{1\}$ is not right.

For every mesurable set $A$, $f^{-1}A$ must be one of the four cases.

$$
f^{-1}A=
\begin{cases}
\emptyset & (0,1\notin A) \\
\mathbb Q & (0\in A, 1\notin A) \\
\mathbb R - \mathbb Q & (0\notin A, 1\in A) \\
\mathbb R & (0,1\in A)
\end{cases}
$$

And for all cases $\emptyset, \mathbb Q, \mathbb R - \mathbb Q, \mathbb R$ is Lebesgue mesurable. $m(\emptyset)=0, m(\mathbb Q)=0, m(\mathbb R - \mathbb Q)=\infty, m(\mathbb R)=\infty$.

So $f$ is Lebesgue mesurable.

If you use the same logic as this, then you can get this proposition:

> For all Lebesgue mesurable set $A\subseteq\mathbb R$, characteristic map $\chi_A:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is Lebesgue mesurable function.

Answer (score 1):

A function is measurable if the preimage of any measurable set is measurable.

The function you gave only has four possible preimages in the first place: if a set contains neither $0$, nor $1$, then its preimage is $\emptyset$. If it contains $0$, but not $1$, then the preimage is $\mathbb R\backslash\mathbb Q$. If it contains $1$, but not $0$, then the preimage is $\mathbb Q$. And if it contains both, the preimage is $\mathbb R$.

All of these are measurable. So the preimage of any set is measurable - that of a measurable set included. So the function is measurable.